# A du-like utility with curses graphic illustration of used space

Tags: linux, open-source, command-line, utility

I occasionally use `du` to explore my disk usage, and find myself having to write elaborate sorting and filtering scripts around it to sort of get a "big picture" of what's going on in a directory. I know that occasionally some kind soul builds a fancier version of a command-line utility with extended functionality and some curses graphics, such as Hisham Muhammad's [`htop`](http://hisham.hm/htop/) as opposed to plain old UNIX [`top`](http://www.unixtop.org/documentation.shtml) (yes, it has a webpage somehow). I was hoping for the same but for `du`.

Obviously requirements: libre, gratis, small, command-line/terminal-based

Answer (score 2):

[Ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) would do it. Has prettyish graphs, is pure curses and available in the repos for leading distros

It's designed for remote use and does most of what you asked for... Big picture of drive usage, with graphs

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

Libre/gratis, curses based, and probably pretty small (but I didn't check)

Comment: Yup, that looks about right.